# debconf warnings despite DEBIAN_FRONTEND inside Docker image

Tags: ubuntu, docker, installation, apt-get

I've got pretty simple Dockerfile

```
FROM ubuntu:14.04
MAINTAINER XXX <xxx@yyy.zzz>
ARG DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive
RUN sudo apt-get -y update && sudo apt-get -y install apache2-utils
```

and I see the following messages during docker build

```
debconf: unable to initialize frontend: Dialog
debconf: (Dialog frontend will not work on a dumb terminal, an emacs shell buffer, or without a controlling terminal.)
debconf: falling back to frontend: Readline
debconf: unable to initialize frontend: Readline
debconf: (This frontend requires a controlling tty.)
debconf: falling back to frontend: Teletype
dpkg-preconfigure: unable to re-open stdin:
```

I've read in different sources, that `ARG DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive` should help, but it doesn't. Build output looks the same with and without it. Is this normal?

My Docker version is 1.12.

---

**UPDATE**

I also tried this

```
ENV DEBIAN_FRONTEND noninteractive
```

and this

```
RUN apt-get -y update && DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive apt-get -y install apache2-utils
```

Warnings message appears each time.

Comment: It's not recommended to set DEBIAN_FRONTEND persistently [[1](https://github.com/docker/docker/issues/4032)],[[2](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#/env)]

Have you tried setting the variable directly for the `RUN` instruction?

Answer (score 0):

It's not recommended to set DEBIAN_FRONTEND persistently [[1](https://github.com/docker/docker/issues/4032)],[[2](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#/env)]

Use this `Dockerfile` to get rid of the warning:

```
FROM ubuntu:14.04
MAINTAINER XXX <xxx@yyy.zzz>
RUN apt-get -y update && DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive apt-get -y install apache2-utils
```

Comment: Tried this, same warning message.

Comment: Also note that I was using ```ARG```, not ```ENV```. I thought it was recommended way for such things.